# How to clean the purge valve of a snorkel?

Tags: cleaning, personal-care

I've had this snorkel for several years now and usually use it in a chlorine pool. There's something disgusting happening to the part close to where I put my mouth. I'm not sure how to clean it. Any suggestions?

[image: photo of side of snorkel]
[image: photo of front of snorkel]

I'm not sure what cleaning agent to use. Since it's going in my mouth it needs to be alright to swallow a little, but if chlorine water hasn't killed it already it needs to be stronger.

The valve at the bottom doesn't open from that side, it's for ejecting water (by blowing out) that fell in the top of the snorkel.

Answer (score 4):

*Vinegar*.

As you say, the chlorine will have killed it, if it was ever alive.  So you need to remove the residue, not kill it.

I soak my snorkel in a bowl of water that has something acidic added, ordinary vinegar is fine.  It won't attack the plastic.

After a couple of hours, it should then wash out if you flush the snorkel with clean water.  Give the valve a good blow afterwards just in case any residue still sits against the seal - it will come out.

Comment: Vinegar and/or lemon juice will work. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a bottle cleaner with appropriate size. Put it inside the snorkel from the top and make circular movements.

[image]

Or you can make something similar to this bottle cleaner.

Cut a sponge in long and narrow piece. Put the piece of sponge in the mouthpiece while holding one end (you need to pull it back after that) and use something flexible from the top to press it down to the valve.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing for that purge valve is to buy a snorkel that doesn't have one.  I snorkeled for years in open water with a plain J-tube snorkel, and never had any scum in my snorkel.  Put a little air bubble into the tube with your face to the surface when you start upward, and the pressure reduction will force the water out and leave just a few drops in the bend.  Those will expel easily from the smooth tube with a vigorous exhalation.  All the soft flex tube, purge valves and such are just money traps.